# Web Api giving error: 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

**Scenario:**

I have an ASP WebAPI service that accept `email` `id` to retrieve the previous password.

But I am having a problem that If I enter a valid `email` `Id` `"Internal server error 500"` is thrown but if a wrong `email` `Id` is entered, then Json with error message is returned.
(If an invalid `email` `id` is entered, then I have a Json with error message returned)

So can please any one guide what to do.

```
var urll = 'api/BeerAppRetrieve';
// var urll = 'api/BeerApp';
var emailId = "anirudh1190@gmail.com";
//$.getJSON(urll + '/' + data)
$.getJSON(urll, { "emailId": emailId })
    .done(function (data) {
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        alert("error" + jqXHR.responseText);
        $('#txtUserName').text('Error: ' + err);
    });
```

My json call..
I want the method to be hit if email id is valid also..
Please help...

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{emailId}",
    defaults: new { emailId = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

My route config.

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "GET, POST")]
public IHttpActionResult GetForgotPassword(String emailId)
{
    MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
    MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("beersavo@gmail.com");
    MyMailMessage.To.Add(emailId);
    MyMailMessage.Subject = "Forgot Password";
    MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    BeerAppUserClass beerAppDal = new BeerAppUserClass();
    String passwrd = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        passwrd = beerAppDal.GetUserPassword(emailId);
    }
    catch (Exception exw)
    {
        return Json(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("MailSend", exw.InnerException.Message));
    }

    if (!passwrd.Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        MyMailMessage.Body = "<table><tr><td>" + "Login to the site with:</td></tr> <tr><td>  UserName: </td><td>" + emailId + "</td></tr> <tr><td> Password:</td><td>" + passwrd + "</td></tr></table>";
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        SMTPServer.Port = 587;
        //SMTPServer.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
        SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "Password@321");
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
            return Json(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("MailSend", "true"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(newKeyValuePair<String,String("MailSend",ex.InnerException.Message));
        }
    }

    return Json(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("MailSend", "empty"));
}
```

Action in the controller

Comment: Have you tried debugging the server-side code?

Comment: `Internal Server Error` ... Start by posting the server code

Comment: Let's see your WebApi Controller/Method/Action. Most people mix up MVC and WebApi routing

Comment: Internal Server Error is about server side error. So you must show us your server side code.

Comment: please show //my code ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more of a comment.. .

though the issue is with having the email in the route - it has a period `.` - this is throwing off your routing. i had the exact same issue on a previous project that had email addresses as ID's

I would wager that when you try it with a bad email the bad string you're trying with doesn't have a period.

Use a querystring, so 'api/BeerAppRetrieve?theemail=theactual@email.com`

or change your route config to accept the period

or you can replace certain characters in the email client side and change them back server side (worst case)

As a **super worst case** you could add the following in your web.config (you should really avoid this otheriwse EVERY request on your site goes through the asp.net pipeline..

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> <!-- add this -->
```

**Update**

In your Javascript change:

```
var urll = 'api/BeerAppRetrieve';
```

to this

```
var urll = 'api/BeerAppRetrieve?emailAddress=anirudh1190@gmail.com';
```

And change your route back to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and change your API controller to

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "GET, POST")]
  public IHttpActionResult GetForgotPassword(String id)
  {
    //my code
  }
```

Comment: I have added route config setting please guide what to do.?

Comment: I have this setting in web config

Comment: Ultimately, use the `querystring` method to get around the dot in the route

Comment: The thing is its working fine in local but wen the api is deployed and I try to use this, it is throwing error.

Comment: Trust me - it is because of the `.` - you likely have a different setting on IIS than your local server.

Comment: So what to do for "." on IIS? And why the wrong email is hitting the method and correct email is not

Comment: What is the `wrong` email? - and per IIS, you need to compare. I don't mean to sound harsh, though I have let you know why it's failing (its most likely scenario) - why not try some of those fixes first?